# Is there any build in Java way to make a Set out of a combination of 2 ints?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

This is my code:

```
private class UniqueClassByTwoIntProperties {
    private final int propertyOne;
    private final int propertyTwo;

    UniqueCase(final int propertyOne, final int propertyTwo) {
        this.propertyOne= propertyOne;
        this.propertyTwo= propertyTwo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(obj instanceof UniqueCase)) {
            return false;
        }

        UniqueClassByTwoIntProperties unique = (UniqueClassByTwoIntProperties) obj;

        return unique.claimApplicationId == claimApplicationId && unique.claimCoverageId == claimCoverageId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(propertyOne, propertyTwo);
    }
}
```

I am looping through a list with objects, where I want to get the unique's in the following way:

```
myList.stream()
      .map(row -> new UniqueClassByTwoIntProperties(row.getOne(), row.getTwo()))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I was wondering if there was a build-in class/method in Java. I have looked into dictionaries and MultiMapValues, but it was a bit hacky.

Comment: `return unique.hashCode() == hashCode();` WHAT? **NO!** This is of course horribly broken, `hashCode` has the variable space of `int` - two `int` have the variable space of `long`. That is literally the point of `hashCode` - two items that are _not `equals`_ **may** have the same `hashCode()` but two items that _are `equals`_ **must** have same `hashCode()`. Please, please **please** read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/2071828). Your code it fundatemally and catastrophically broken.

Comment: What is the type of `myList`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Woops, I am embarresed about that mistake. I hope I properly implemented it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do it as:

```
Set<UniqueClassByTwoIntProperties> uniques = new HashSet<>(myList);
```

*Aside*: Make sure the `hashCode` and `equals` of the objects are implemented correctly for the object to be comparable.

If you just want the `List` of uniques then you can use [`Stream.distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) as :

```
List<UniqueClassByTwoIntProperties> uniques = myList.stream()
                                 .distinct() // for unique objects
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Apart from the broken `equals` which will cause `Set` to behave very strangely.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Agreed, that's what made me place that side note. Though answering to focus on the actual question.

Comment: As another aside, in the OPs example they are using a `Stream` - could you mention `Collectors.toSet()` and `distinct()`? (+1 either way)

Comment: @BoristheSpider `distinct` is not required while collecting `toSet`, hence the current solution proposed with the use of streams is correct.

Comment: I meant as two alternatives. If the OP wants a `List` of unique items then `distinct` will do the trick. Otherwise `toSet`. Your answer only covers copying the `List` to a `Set` after already building the `List`. The answer doesn't quite avoid the OPs problem as the OP needs to create the `UniqueClassByTwoIntProperties` - this seems to be a way to "override" equality for the sake of this particular uniqueness constraint.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Mentioned in the answer about the two alternatives.